# Does aggregation (OOP Concept) in Python restrict the child object from being owned by other objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, aggregation

I read this statement that "Aggregation occurs when objects have their own life cycle and child object can associate with only one parent object". However, it works fine for my code:-

```
class Country:
    def __init__(self, name=None, population=0):
        self.name = name
        self.population = population

    def printDetails(self):
        print("Country Name:", self.name)
        print("Country Population", self.population)


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, country):
        self.name = name
        self.country = country

    def printDetails(self):
        print("Person Name:", self.name)
        self.country.printDetails()

class Man:
    def __init__(self, name, country):
        self.name = name
        self.country = country

    def printDetails(self):
        print("Person Name:", self.name)
        self.country.printDetails()



c = Country("Wales", 1500)
p = Person("Joe", c)
m = Man('John', c);
p.printDetails()
m.printDetails()

c.printDetails()
```

Comment: Your child classes `Person` and `Man` only have one parent object `Country`. How is this an argument against what you quoted?

Comment: The parent objects are `Person` and `Man` because they own the object `Country`, right?

Comment: No, it's the other way around. When you have a one-to-many relationship, the one is the parent and the many are children. So all the inhabitants of a country are the children.

Comment: I think that's exactly what the OP is asking about, @Barmar.  In an OO sense, a parent (or I would prefer "owner") of an object O is one that has a reference to O or otherwise incorporates O in some way.  Multiple objects having references to O might negate that, but that doesn't turn it around. It just means that the relationship between them does not satisfy the usual definition of an aggregation -- in either direction.

Comment: References by themselves don't define parent-child relationships.

Comment: Agreed, @Barmar, I did not mean to imply that I had given a complete definition.  However, not being able to traverse the OP's relationships between `Country` and `Man` or `Country` and `Person` from the `Country` side is inconsistent with characterizing the `Country` as "parent" of the others.  Relationship multiplicity by itself doesn't define parent-child relationships, either.

Comment: Right, it's defined by the role they play in the application. And often there will be a one-to-many relationship from parent to child. Aggregation means making a collection of things, such as a country having a list of all its inhabitants. I don't understand the description quoted.

Comment: This whole question would probably be more appropriate for [softwareengineering.se], it's generic to all OOP, not about Python programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I read this statement that "Aggregation occurs when objects have their
> own life cycle and child object can associate with only one parent
> object". However, it works fine for my code [...]

You misunderstand.  The statement you quoted is part of a *definition* of "aggregation".  You can certainly write code that does things differently, but inasmuch as it does so, it is not demonstrating aggregation -- at least, not according to the definition you're looking at.